# pyspark: datatype changing function

Tags: python

I have a iris.csv dataset. I loaded csv file into RDD and I should change all numeric values into float. I tried to convert it into data frame but it said "can not infer schema for type: class 'str'"
the whole day I tried to do it but I could not. as I am beginner could you help me please

```
    irisRDD = sc.textFile("C:/Users/fox/Desktop/KOREAN/iris.csv")
>>> newirisRDD = irisRDD.toDF()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 61, in toDF
    return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 605, in createDataFrame
    return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 628, in _create_dataframe
    rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 425, in _createFromRDD
    struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 405, in _inferSchema
    schema = _infer_schema(first, names=names)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1067, in _infer_schema
    raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: share the code for us , then we can help you way easier

Comment: And add a sample from the file ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).